# Replace '/' with '_' in specefic column in a CSV file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file (test.csv):

```
"test1", "https://test.com/file1.jpg"
"test/23", "https://test.com/file1.jpg"
"test34", "https://test.com/file78.jpg"
"test/23", "https://test.com/file1.jpg"
```

I need to replace '/' in the first column with '_' using python.
I did look at pandas and other examples, but they only show how to replace the entire csv file.

I use the csv fil to download a list of images using this script:

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from datetime import datetime
import csv

with open ('test.csv') as images:
    images = csv.reader(images)

img_count = 0
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
for image in images:
    urlretrieve(image[1],
            '{}.jpg'.format(image[1]+'_'+image[0]))
    img_count += 1
    print("Current Time =", current_time)
    print(img_count)
```

The problem is that the script fails because it cant use / in the file names.

Comment: You can address this problem in many ways. Please include the technique you want/need to use, and show code samples of what you have done already.

Comment: I just edited my question. I hope it make sense

Comment: Note that modifying a string is not related to reading from a csv file-- they are two separate tasks. Perhaps this is why your question is getting downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your csv file is as you show, the first column is `image[0]` and you can modify it with `image[0].replace("/", "_")`. Note that this does not modify the string in place-- it returns a new value. You don't say if you are trying to store the edited data in a new csv file, but if you are, you'd store the modified string in the record like this:

```
image[0] = image[0].replace("/", "_")
```